# How do I disable the console LOG on eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate

I've read a lot about this topic on different places, but it's very confusing.
I am using mainly two frameworks, hibernate and java-asterisk.
What I have on the console is the following :

```
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gomobile]
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gomobile]
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gomobile]
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gomobile]
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl connect
INFO: Connecting to localhost:5038
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
INFO: Connected via Asterisk Call Manager/2.5.0
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
WARNING: Unsupported protocol version 'Asterisk Call Manager/2.5.0'. Use at your own risk.
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl doLogin
INFO: Successfully logged in
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:04 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl buildEvent
INFO: No event class registered for event type 'fullybooted', attributes: {status=Fully Booted, event=FullyBooted, privilege=system,all}. Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:06 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl doLogin
INFO: Determined Asterisk version: Asterisk 1.6
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:06 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl disconnect
INFO: Closing socket.
Jan 14, 2015 3:25:06 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerReaderImpl run
INFO: Terminating reader thread: No more lines available: null
```

Here are the dependencies I have :

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
```

I am running eclipse luna on a xUBUNTU 14.04.
Thanks !

Comment: What does eclipse have to do with this? You need to configure java.util.logging and/or log4j to get the logging you want.

Comment: Are you want to disable hibernate logs or entire eclipse console logs ? , If you want to disable eclipse console log, redirect all logs to file(google it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable or reduce hibernate logs add following dependencies (Maven artifact notation <groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>) to your project:

- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.6
- log4j:log4j:1.2.14

Versions can also be newer.

Then add a resource file with the name "log4j.properties" to your project, so that it appears later in the root folder of your packaged jar file. Start with following log4j configuration to turn off "org.hibernate" log messages:

```properties
# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO

# Log appender for package stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%p] %c.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n

# Log appender for org.hibernate
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF,hibernate
log4j.appender.hibernate.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%p] %c.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hibernate=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# Further log appenders
# ...
```

Choose a log level for your root logger as you wish and define another log appender for "org.asteriskjava".

Comment: Hello, thank your for your answer. I am new to Java and I am not using maven in program. I am using the latest version of eclipse and I add jars manually.

Comment: I found a way to install maven, your answer worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your neat answer. Thank you a lot, and welcome to Morocco anytime !!